# Having an issue with my length validation class

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create my own custom validator class that I can check the length of a user supplied value. I know there are plenty of already created options out there, but I am trying to learn PHP and creating my own work is the approach I want to take.

I will try and explain what I am doing here and hopefully I don't lose anyone. I will try and let the code talk for me as much as possible. I will start out by showing my multidimensional array that I will use to get the posted information:

```
$input_array = array('username' => array( 'value'=> $_POST['username'],
                                          'min'  => 3,
                                          'max'  => 20
                                         ),
                     'password' => array( 'value'=> $_POST['password'],
                                          'min'  => 8,
                                          'max'  => 16
                                         ),
                     'email'    => array( 'value'=> $_POST['email'],
                                          'min'  => 6,
                                          'max'  => 50
                                         )
                     );
```

create the object:

```
$obj = new Validate(array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$input_array));
$vl  = $obj->ValidateLength();
```

So here I will show the class:

```
class Validate
{
    private $inputArray;
    public function __construct($inputAray)
    {
        $this->inputArray = $inputArray;
    }
    public function ValidateLength()
    {
        $larray = array('error'=>'','data'=> array());
        foreach($this->inputArray as $k => $i)
        {
            if(strlen($i['value']) < $i['min'])
            {
                $larray['error'] = true;
                $larray['data'][$k] = ' must be at least '.$i['min'].' characters long';
            }
        }
        return json_encode($larray);
    }
}
```

What the class does is checks the input value and sees if it fits within the `min` and `max` I put in the array. If it finds an error it changes the error value to true and puts all the errors in an array to return in JSON format.

Now I have this little guy:

```
$length = json_decode($obj->ValidateLength(),true);
```

which will convert the JSON into another multidimensional array like so:

**var_dump($length)**

```
array(2){
 ["error"]=>
 bool(true)
 ["data"]=>
 array(1){
 ["username"]=>
 string(35)" must be at least 3 charracters long"
 ["password"]=>
 string(35)" must be at least 8 characters long"
 }
}
```

So here is where the problem arises. I have this conditional that notices that there is an error and should print out the error message for  `username` and `password`:

```
$key   = implode("\n",array_keys($length['data']));
$value = implode(", ",array_values($length['data']));
if($length['error'])
{
    print("Error :\n\n".strtoupper($key).$value);
}
else
{
    print('everything is within parameters');
}
```

What I get is this:

```
Error:

USERNAME
PASSWORD must be at least 3 characters long, must be at least 8 characters long
```

What I want is this:

```
Error:

USERNAME must be at least 3 characters long
PASSWORD must be at least 8 characters long
```

A few thing to note is, I am trying to avoid a `foreach()` if at all possble in the conditional to make it clean an easy. Also keeping modularization in mind, I want to be able to change `username` `password` `email` in the first initial array that gets the user input to work with other projects.

If did't explain myself too well, and if you are lost at what I am trying to achieve please let me know and I will try better. Thanks in advance for having a looksie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just add the name of the field to the error?

```
$larray['data'][$k] = sprintf('%s must be at least %d characters long',$k,$i['min']);
```

I don't know if that helps at all?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will play with that idea and see what I come up with. I have it stuck in my head the the return from the validator class must be in JSON format in order to have more control with the returned information.

Comment: You can keep the JSON,  just have append the field to the error since that's what you want anyway, reduces the time to execute.

Comment: So your thinking the JSON would look like this -> `{"error":"true","data":{"username":"username must be at least 3 characters long","password":"password must be at least 8 characters long"}}`?